# Google calendar api integration with classic asp

Tags: asp.net, .net, google-api

I have a working google calendar  integration with Console and web as explained in https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet .
I am unable to get any direct way to integrate the same with classic asp.

Is there any way, I can integrate google calendar with Oauth2 in classic asp ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean "classic ASP.NET" (as opposed to ASP.NET Core) or do you mean "classic ASP" (as opposed to ASP.NET at all)?

Comment: I mean classic asp as VB script

Comment: Right - in that case, you wouldn't be doing anything with .NET... I don't think we have any actual support for VB, but you'd basically want to use the REST API directly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @JonSkeet . "use the REST API directly" - are you suggesting to go with java-script ?

Comment: No, I'm saying that you make a request to the REST API as described here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/ - you can do that from whatever language you like; it's just making web requests. Admittedly you'll need to find a JSON parser and sort out authentication, which may be tricky in such a legacy environment...

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the excellent CHilkat components. He provides examples about ways to consume many API's, including Google Calendar.
You can get examples on this website : http://rest-examples.chilkat.io/google_calendar/asp/default.cshtml

The main website with extended docs is located at https://www.chilkatsoft.com/